# How to install .CER file for apache ssl certificate in RHEL

Tags: linux, redhat, ssl-certificate

Recently I tried to install an SSL certificate for my RHEL 8 server. So, I sent .csr file to the
Certification Authority (CA) and I received .cer file. Now, I am new to this so I don't know .cer file needs to be changed into a .crt file for the Linux server. or how to install this .cer file for RHEL 8. Can anyone provide me with any clue about this? I found this link

https://www.ssldragon.com/blog/install-an-ssl-certificate-on-red-hat-linux/

but it's not useful at all

Also my application php. So, I added my .cer file path to /etc/php.ini file

openssl.cafile= /etc/httpd/conf/key.cer

Any clue will help me. Thanks

Comment: A server certificate is probably not the right data for openssl.cafile (I'd expect that needs a CA certificate)

Answer (score 0):

In Linux file extensions are mostly only somewhat informational to users and not relevant for applications. A particular  file extensions  usually doesn't the define/limit the function of a file.

None of the applications I know really care if I point them at `certname.cer` `certname.pem` or `certname` or whatever other file name as long as that file has the right content with the correct encoding.

I *suspect* that when you actually look at `certname.cer` it will already be in the [PEM](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/PEM) format (base64 ASCII encoded) that most applications expect. That looks a bit like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...abcd...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Using the certificate depends on which actual service you're configuring. All of the have their own configuration directives and peculiarities.

In many cases you can point for example an Apache [`SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile) directive to the same file used in setting up SSL in Dovecot [`ssl_cert = </path/to/cert.pem`](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/dovecot_ssl_configuration/)